# When is the katakana form of wo (ヲ) used?

Tags: katakana

I'm pretty new to Japanese, and I've been trying to learn hiragana and katakana. I know that in hiragana, wo (を) is used only for as an object particle, and it is always pronounced like o (お).

This made me wonder what the katakana form (ヲ) would be used for, since o (オ) would be used for anything with an "o" sound. Even if a direct object is written in katakana, the o that follows would still be in hiragana, correct?

Comment: 「を」also using as non-particle too in names like 眞鍋かをり

Comment: +1 This is a great beginner question.

Comment: @YOU: AFAIK Kaori Manabe is the only person using を in her name, which is much more commonly written as かおり.

Comment: @PhilipSeyfi: I seriously doubt that she's the *only* person to do so. In fact, I believe I've seen a few other names with を; but I can't remember where off the top of my head.

Comment: one example of ヲ in Katakana http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13404/3786

Comment: My wife name contains wo, but in katakana it is written ワォ instead of ヲ. So, in nowadays I never see the real use of ヲ in Japan.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Some of the posts indicate that ヲ is very rare. This isn't really the case. In general Japanese usage, yes, it is very rare. However, if you have all-katakana text, then you will *always* find を written as ヲ.

All-katakana text might be encountered in child-oriented media such as video games. I have seen plenty of old games that use only katakana, such as [Downtown Nekketsu Monogatari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_City_Ransom) (known in the US as River City Ransom), [Moero!! Junior Basket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoops_(video_game)) (known in the US as Hoops), and the original MSX/NES version of [Metal Gear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Gear_(video_game)#Famicom_.2F_NES). ヲ is used in all of them. (Some of these games used all kana due to technical limitations, but sometimes all-kana text is a stylistic choice.)

In manga and video games, robots will often speak in katakana, much like using an all-caps "digital" font in English.

Transcriptions of morse code, telegrams, etc. will also use all-katakana text and therefore ヲ. So usage of ヲ is alive and well, it's just that the contexts where it's appropriate are infrequent except in certain media.

Comment: As Kef and Amanda point out, manga like to use all-katakana to give a certain style. Tetsuka Osamu for example tends to make all his foreign characters speak in all-katakana to emphasise the fact they aren't actually Japanese (and are either speaking a foreign language that's translated for our convenience, or speak Japanese with a foreign accent). I also used to think ヲ was of no use... until I read one of those...

Answer (score 12):

Another usage was in some pre-WWII documents, which swapped hiragana and katakana as they are used currently.  e.g., ミンナガ協力出来ルヨウニ日本語ヲ勉強シマショウ。  I did a search on this and it may have been only for government documents.

Comment: Nitpick: the small ョ was not used back then. It would be written `~勉強シマセウ`

Answer (score 10):

It's sometimes used when whole sentences are written in katakana. One instance is, as Brendan noted, during WWII and for a short while after.

Another is often in comics, to indicate that the speaker is either a foreigner with a thick accent, or a robot/text-to-speech program with awkward pronunciation.

Comment: here's one example for [robotic speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13404/3786)

Answer (score 4):

ヲ has practically fallen out of use these days. If you find it at all it's usually a stylistic choice, for example as notably used in [new Evangelion movies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebuild_of_Evangelion) together with ヱ: ヱヴァンゲリヲン.

For automated data processing, information sometimes needs to be in (half-width) katakana (older government systems, for example). There you may find ｦ in place of を (though these systems mostly store names, where を is rare anyway).

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes hiragana is replaced with katakana in dialogue for stylistic reasons, or to indicate a particular speech style.  For example, I have seen katakana used in place of hiragana in manga to indicate that the speaker is actually speaking another language.  In those circumstances, ヲ is used as the object marker instead of を.

Answer (score 4):

It is very rare and you will most likely never encounter it. I even listened to a Japanese radio show where native Japanese were saying it makes no sense to have this character anymore. The only time I have ever seen it used is when highlighting a sentence in manga, similar to how we use italics, where the entire sentence was written in katakana.

Comment: I voted this down since I see ヲ probably a few dozen times a year.  That's rare, but "you will most likely never encounter it" is probably not true if you use Japanese more than casually.

Answer (score 4):

Katakana used to be used for telegrams and official documents so ヲ would have been more commonly seen. The Wikipedia article on Katakana gives a good background on how Katakana and Hiragana usage has changed over the years. Even 100 years ago it was quite different.

Answer (score 3):

The use of katakana ヲ is quite rare indeed; as you surmise, the use as a particle is Hiragana in modern Japanese. In older dialects, Katakana was used for particles as well, however, and you can see ヲ in use there. In modern times, it's also occasionally used for ironic or stylistic purposes, such as in [ヲタク](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/keyword/%A5%F2%A5%BF%A5%AF).

Answer (score 3):

Outside of katakana used for emphasis, you may see it in names, mostly as a stylistic variant of 「かおる」 (カヲル).

Comment: Actually, in that case it's not a stylistic variant, but rather the traditional spelling of the word. The ヲ in ヲタク is purely stylistic though (since the original spelling was just オタク).

Answer (score 1):

On my wife's great grand father doctor's certificate, there seems to a lots of ヲ　and other than other katakana and no hiragana. Packed full of kanji.

Comment: if that's a certificate at the early 20th century then definitely Katakana would be used in places of the Hiragana nowadays

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/59rp7g/early_20th_century_japanese_text_consisting_only/