# What does じゃあーりませんか mean?

Tags: kansai-ben, academic-japanese, japanese-to-english

Or what is written on this image? I think this is in Osaka kansai dialect.

[image]

And also, what is here?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Japanese Language Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, as presently worded, your question is 'off-topic' (it is a translation/transcription request without demonstrating any of your own research effort). Please be sure to read the community guidelines in the Help Center, over what sorts of questions are acceptable/desirable, and then consider editing your post; otherwise, it may be closed.

Answer (score 3):

> これまったカンペーさんじゃあーりませんか

This is 「これはまた、カンペーさんじゃありませんか」 ("Oh, is it you again, Kanpei!") but said with an eccentric accent. じゃありませんか (ではありませんか, じゃないですか, etc) is a way to express the speaker's surprise. See: [Meaning of 言うではありませんか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65231/5010)

Isn't the speaker チャーリー浜? This これまった + あーりませんか is one of his signature gags ([video](https://youtu.be/Q6OW-9RZUMA)) which became popular in 1990. He often played the role of a snobbish businessperson, and his あーりませんか is not Kansai-ben but more like the [stereotypical gaijin-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65033/5010).

> #### [チャーリー浜](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E6%B5%9C)
>
> 吉本新喜劇では「**アメリカかぶれ**のキザなお坊ちゃん」「キザなヤクザ」などの役どころが多く、大阪離れした奇異な言葉遣い（「**…じゃあ～りませんか**」など）で印象をつけた後、劇の最後に大阪弁をまくしたててオチをつける、というコントラストで人気を得た。

どんなもんや is a Kansai-ben version of どんなものだ ("How was this?", "Did you see?"). I may be wrong but I guess this is from 島木譲二, another Kansai comedian who often played the role of a funny yakuza. カンペー is 間寛平.

Comment: Yes this is words of Charlie Hama and Kanpei Hazama of Yoshimoto. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Is there a way to tell if じゃありませんか is used to express surprise or to state a rhetorical question?

Answer (score 0):

じゃありませんか？　＝　is it not ___? (this is a rhetorical question, as the speaker is stating something that is either obvious, or to which he can only think of one answer.)

as for the ー in the middle, I can not see but perhaps this is an old person speaking? it is there to make the reading sound more like the way the character speaks. Like is we write Pirate speech in er funay way maytee, arr. Make sense? This is very common in マンガ.