# Meaning of katakana at the end of okurigana in this song lyrics

Tags: katakana, song-lyrics

Listening to Japanese music I stumbled upon [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nK75Viqu0xI) called 僕たちの失敗　by 森田童子. I liked it so I went to look up for the [lyrics](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/%E3%81%BC%E3%81%8F%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%B1%E6%95%97-boku-tachi-no-shippai-our-failure.html) and its meaning, and there is a part of those in which something is used that I would like to have explained.

The thing is, at some points in these lyrics katakana is used at the end of okurigana. What's the meaning? What's the usage? Why are those sentences written like that?

> 弱虫だったんだヨネ
>
> チャーリー・パーカー見つけたヨ
>
> ぼくを忘れたカナ
>
> 昔の話だネ

Comment: Refer to the answer to this post: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/64987 , particularly the part about 'eccentric personality'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't okurigana. They're just normal sentence-final particles. They're normally written in hiragana. Sometimes Japanese people will use katakana to add special emphasis on a word, but in this case it's just an affectation, like a girl writing a heart instead of the dot on an i.

Comment: Yes, I meant they were written at the end of the okurigana. Thanks for your response.