# Which alphabet should I use when combining a Japanese word with an English word?

Tags: orthography

I know Japanese words are written with kanji and hiragana, and katakana is for foreign words and exclamations.  But I want to write "yanderenee", which is yandere + renee (my name).  Which alphabet should I use for this?

The purpose is to be used as my blog title, which is written in English and is not likely to be read by Japanese speakers.  So it probably doesn't matter how I write it.  But I would like it to be correct, if there is a correct way to do something unconventional like that.

It could also be thought of as just yandere nee, as in, nee as an exclamation.  In which case it would be kanji/hiragana.  But does it change anything that this is supposed to be a Japanese+English word combined?  Or do I have freedom to choose how it should be written?

Answer (score 3):

Both foreign names and [ヤンデレ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_anime_and_manga#Character_traits) happen to be written with katakana, so you can simply use katakana for "yanderenee", too. →「ヤンデレニー」

You may be wondering why ヤンデレ is almost always written with katakana although it's a Japanese slang term. This is because:

1. ヤンデレ is derived from ツンデレ ([tsundere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsundere)).
2. ツンデレ is a [portmanteau word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) made of ツンツン and デレデレ.
3. Both ツンツン and デレデレ are Japanese mimetic words, which are often written with katakana.

Actually many Japanese-origin words are written with katakana for various reasons. And mixed-foreign-Japanese portmanteau tend to be in katakana, too.

See:

- [Why is カラオケ (karaoke) written in katakana?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14531/5010)
- [Why are katakana preferred over hiragana or kanji sometimes?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1930/5010)