# What are the rules or instances in which a kana indication of の is dropped?

Tags: grammar, nuances, readings

I've noticed that, in instances such as 「天叢雲剣」{あめのむらくものつるぎ}, の is present in only the pronounced version where it should also be included in the written version. This is not the only instance I have seen of this situation, though I cannot remember the others off the top of my head.

Grammatically, the pronounced version is correct. What exactly are the rules for omitting the の、then?

I assume this is related to the history of the Japanese language; my question is not about why this came to be - just the rules.

Comment: There are no rules. Some words were just coined as orthography was changing.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there is a strict rule about this, but AFAIK this happens in some proper nouns of ancient Japanese myths. Probably the most famous example would be [ヤマタ**ノ**オロチ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamata_no_Orochi) (八岐大蛇). You can find examples in 古事記 and 日本書紀.

Since these proper nouns are really old, no one today know the etymology of these words, and [the kanji assigned to these words are basically ateji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13788/5010).

Apparently some people in the past thought it was a good idea to indicate the word boundary by inserting の when reading. This is a convention only found in this limited situation, and we are very unlikely to use this rule to coin a new word.

Another similar usage of "unwritten の" is の found in historical person names. の was pronounced after a clan name (源頼朝 read as みなもと**の**よりとも). This is discussed in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_name#Historical_names). As you can see in the link, the naming convention of historical person names was very complicated, and in general, Japanese students learn these names without wondering when の is required after a "family name".