# Is 天火明命 read as 'ten-ka-mei-mei'?

Tags: kanji, readings, multiple-readings

I've been playing maimai, the Japanese arcade rhythm game for a while. It offers a song named **天火明命**, which a few of my friends pronounce as 'ten-ka-mei-mei'.

However, [the official Twitter account of the game specifies it as 'a-me-no-ho-a-ka-ri'](https://twitter.com/maimai_official/status/866490300448989184) (**あめのほあかり**), which confuses me.

So what's the right way to pronounce the name? Is the "official" pronunciation simply the author's preference, or has actually been used in the past?

Comment: ググってみたらすぐ[これ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A9%E7%81%AB%E6%98%8E%E5%91%BD)を見つけました

Comment: あ、ちなみに「のみこと」は神の敬称のようなものなんです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

天火明命 is the name of a god in ancient Japanese mythology. 天 = あめ, 火 = ほ, 明 = あかり. (の is a particle; 命 (みこと) is a kind of suffix for deities.) See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenohoakari) for details.

The kanji of [god names in Japanese mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Japanese_deities) are generally based on kun-yomi, ateji or jukujikun, because they existed before Japanese people learned kanji and their on-yomi from China. See also: [Why is "Yamata no Orochi" written in katakana?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13788/5010)