# Is しゃぶしゃぶ typically written in hiragana rather than katakana?

Tags: orthography, katakana, hiragana, spelling, onomatopoeia

Is しゃぶしゃぶ typically written in hiragana rather than katakana? If so, why is it written in hiragana?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabu-shabu) says that it is onomatopoeia:

> The term is an onomatopoeia, derived from the sound emitted when the
>   ingredients are stirred in the cooking pot.

And I thought that onomatopoeia [was](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1931/91) typically [done](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Japanese/Vocabulary/Onomatopoeia) in katakana (though the latter citation gives some exceptions).

Comment: @hippietrail Wikipedia says it's onomatopoeia, not mimetic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabu-shabu . I'd be inclined to agree, because all uncooked meat looks the same to me.

Comment: There are some contradictory “standards/suggestions” whether onomatopoeia should be written in kanakana or hiragana. People generally use both and prefer one to another in individual words.

Comment: @hippietrail from the Wikipedia article: "derived from the sound emitted when the ingredients are stirred in the cooking pot."

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: OK great then this one really is onomatopoeia. Note that I was sneakily careful not to say it wasn't, just to wonder aloud about it.

Comment: @hippietrail I do that as well.

Comment: Just to point out... しゃぶしゃぶ is not actually 擬音語・擬声語 here. It's *derived* from onomatopoeia, but does not actually work as a representation of the sound anymore. The general tendency of writing 擬音語 in katakana would not need to apply. (Note that wikipedia's definition of onomatopoeia is wide enough to be practically useless, but is largely irrelevant to Japanese)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always written in hiragana. I can't tell you why though. Allegedly it was named しゃぶしゃぶ because of the sound it makes when you take the beef slice through the hot water twice with your chopsticks.

The word しゃぶしゃぶ is never used for other purposes than to refer to the cuisine, at least in contemporary Japan.

Comment: For what it's worth, [「擬態語はひらがな、擬音語はカタカナ」教育の功罪](http://www.excite.co.jp/News/reviewbook/20140108/E1389109814909.html)