# Is it okay to switch from kanji to hiragana in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, kanji, katakana, hiragana

I'm learning Japanese but I find it extremely difficult to write out
exams in kanji. The hiragana version is much easier but I'm not sure if it's okay to do that.

For example, I would like to write

> 今日は**試験**だ。

as

> 今日は**しけん**だ。

Is that okay?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to write?

Comment: The app im using uses the example of "today is exam" 今日は試験だ。

Comment: And how would you like to write it?  (This will help users on the site understand your question better so they can write a specific answer.)

Comment: I would want to write it like 今日はしけん

Comment: That's a switch from kanji to hiragana, not hiragana to katakana.

Comment: Ok. I wasnt sure which one it was. But my question is if its okay to do that in one sentence.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [When should I replace kanji with hiragana?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8315/542) ?

Comment: 今日はしけんだ。ok if you no japanese. or if you small kid also ok. if you 20 year old japanese no ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think how to write Japanese sentences basically go as follow.

You had better write kanji designated for everyday use. If not. the sentences are possibly seemed that they are written by children or the person who doesn't know kanji. However words are sometimes purposely written in Hiragana to show a softness. This is a related link. [Why is the place's official name written as "なら工藝館" (rather than "奈良工藝館")?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/35785/why-is-the-places-official-name-written-as-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89%e5%b7%a5%e8%97%9d%e9%a4%a8-rather-than-%e5%a5%88%e8%89%af%e5%b7%a5%e8%97%9d%e9%a4%a8/35792#35792)

Katakana is usually used in imported and onomatopoeic words.

These aren't exact rules but you had better follow them unless you are advanced-level Japanese learner.