# Why the movies Space Battleship Yamato title don't use Kanji for Yamato but katakana?

Tags: kanji, katakana, anime

The movies wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato

The movies title (宇宙戦艦ヤマト) write Yamato (ヤマト) as katakana. However, Yamato is Japanese word, which is available in Kanji (大和).

大和 also the name of Yamato Battleship. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_battleship_Yamato)

As I learned that Katakana use for foreign word, technical word, sound, ...

Comment: Related: [Why is Toyota typically written in Katakana? (トヨタ)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/31078/5010)

Answer (score 2):

When a name is in a title, they are often rendered in kana even if kanji is available, especially as kanji for names can be read differently.

And katakana is often used simply as a stylistic choice, to make it "pop" so to speak.