# How to understand チラツ

Tags: words

How to understand チラツ ?

My textbook gives "leaflet" as a translation. It's in katakana, though, so I'm looking for a corresponding English word, but what is it?

Comment: You mean ちら**し** / チラ**シ** (=散らし), right? Could you clarify what you mean by `corresponding English word`? *leaflet* is already a possible English translation...?

Comment: It's チラシ, derived from 散らす if I'm not mistaken.  Fun fact: I had a few thousand game chirashi at one point. O_o

Comment: Katakana can be used for non-borrowed words in some circumstances. This is presumably one such circumstance. cf. http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1930

Comment: Btw., even borrowed words often stem from other languages than English...

Comment: Good katakana life! http://pochamarama.tumblr.com/post/28737421770/what-is-with-katakana

Answer (score 2):

"Flyers" > "Leaflets"

The word would most often refer to the (advertising) flyers that are inserted in newspapers.  In Japan, many flyers are also thrown into your mailbox (without your permission).

It is 「チラ**シ**」, not 「チラ**ツ**」.  It is the シ in サシスセソ, not the ツ in タチツテト.

Finally, forget the kanji some people mentioned in the comments above for now.  To refer to "flyers", 「チラシ」 is basically never written using that kanji.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean チラシ?  If so, this is just 散らし written in katakana.