# How to translate "もしかしてそのスーシおニュー？"?

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm attempting to translate something but this sentence is confusing me.
It's the "お" and "スーシ" that I don't understand.
I hope this isn't too dumb of a question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ツ ≠ シ**

**ツ ≒ つ** and **シ ≒ し**.

「スーシ」 is how many non-Japanese people pronounce 「すし」.

Jokes aside, the word you saw would probably be 「スー**ツ**」 instead of 「スー**シ**」.

「スー**ツ**」 means a "suit", the clothes.　「スー**シ**」 does not exist.

「おニュー」 is a **comical** way to say "brand-new" or just "new".　「お」 is the honorific prefix for politeness.  This is a very exceptional usage of 「お」.

***"Is that a brand-new suit by any chance?"*** would be my translation.

Come back if that does not make sense for the context.

Related: [How to understand チラツ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21770/how-to-understand-%e3%83%81%e3%83%a9%e3%83%84/21775#21775)

Comment: What is the ≒ symbol?  (Apparently Google doesn't recognize symbols, so I don't even know how to look it up.)

Comment: @Kimball: 'is approximately the same as'; [≒ seems to be a CJK thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%89%92#Unicode)