# Why was "アオ" used instead of ”あお”?

Tags: orthography

I was reading a picture book, and there was this sentence:
アオくて　ちいさな　ぼくのイス。

Why is "ao" and "isu" written in katakana and not hiragana?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [***Why are katakana preferred over hiragana or kanji sometimes?***](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/why-are-katakana-preferred-over-hiragana-or-kanji-sometimes/1931).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done because it makes it easier to read and understand when no *kanji* are used.

## Easy to read (general usage)

> [青]{あお}くて[小]{ちい}さな[僕]{ぼく}の[椅子]{いす}。

## Normal(this question)

> アオくて　ちいさな　ぼくのイス。

## Hard to read (hard to understand)

> あおくて　ちいさな　ぼくのいす。

## Hardest to read (this might not be understandable)

> あおくてちいさなぼくのいす。

## Impossible to read (joke :-P)

> あおくてち　いさなぼ　くのいす。