# Is there an "I awlyas tghuhot slpeling was ipmorantt!" example in Japanese?

Tags: spelling

I read this article [http://www.gate.net/~labooks/wholeword.html](http://www.gate.net/%7Elabooks/wholeword.html) and I actually read a Chinese version,

> 研表究明，汉字的序顺并不定一能影阅响读，比如当你看完这句话后，才发这现里的字全是都乱的。

So I am thinking is there a Japanese version of it ?

Comment: Tub It'ns spilnelg raylel prontamti ! The more you're gonna shake the more spelling proves to be important. If it works so great in English it is because words are long and do not look like so much to each other in general.

Comment: Unscrambled: 研究表明，漢字的順序並不一定能影響閱讀，比如當你看完這句話後，才發現這裏的字全都是亂的。 (*...the study showed that the specific order of Chinese characters don't necessarily affect reading comprehension; for example, only after you've read this sentence would you have discovered that the characters here are completely scrambled*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There you go.

(Body must be at least 30 characters.)

[image]

Comment: 「こんちには　みさなん　おんげきですか」でググると結構ヒットします -> https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF+%E3%81%BF%E3%81%95%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93+%E3%81%8A%E3%82%93%E3%81%92%E3%81%8D+%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B&oq=%E3%81%93&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j69i60l3j69i65j69i59.7237j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 オリジナルのソースはわかりませんでした・・・

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit surprised that there's a Chinese version. I wonder if there's a good Japanese version with lots of Kanji in it.

> http://www.yukawanet.com/archives/4191006.html のキャッシュです。

こんちには みさなん おんげき ですか？　わしたは げんき です。 
この ぶんょしう は いりぎす の ケブンッリジ だがいく の  
けゅきんう の けっか にんんげ は もじ を にしんき する とき  
その さしいょ と さいご の もさじえ あいてっれば 
じばんゅん は めくちちゃゃ でも ちんゃと よめる という  
けゅきんう に もづいとて わざと もじの じんばゅん を  
いかれえて あまりす。どでうす？　ちんゃと よゃちめう でしょ？

> 実際にケンブリッジ大学でこの文章が認識できてしまうと言う研究がおこなわれているかどうかは、実際のところ今だに不明だ、一部情報によると都市伝説ではないのかと言われているようだ。ただ、この文章が読めてしまうという不思議な現象は、日本語のみならず海外でも知られている話のようだ。
>
> 現段階ではなぜ読めるのか、科学的な根拠はないにしろ、人間は単語を1文字1文字読んで認識するのではなく、ある程度かいつまんで脳内で文章を組み立てているのではないかと推測される。つまり、記述された文章はあくまで、パーツ・素材のようなもので、それを個人個人が脳内で文章を作るのだ。
>
> ちなみにこれを漢字に直すと読めなくなる。

こんにちわ、さ皆んお気元ですか？は私気元です <-- *** This is incorrectly done !

> 多くの日本人は、誤字として認識する。これは漢字がその前後の文脈によって読み方が変わるため、脳内に入る前に、一度整理するからだと思われる。それ以前に、『気元』などと言う日本語は存在しないわ！とストッパーも入るため、漢字では難しいのだ。
>
> さて、これを踏まえて皆様も不思議と読めてしまう日本語で、お手紙を書いて
> おもとちだを、ビクッリさてせみてはいかがうだろか ?

*** A correct version would be (may be):

こんちには、 皆さんお元気すでか？ 私は元気です