# Is this character speaking gibberish?

Tags: meaning, katakana

I'm playing a Japanese game and attempting to translate for myself what the characters are saying. I've run into one very odd character who I can't understand at all - I'm not sure if what they're saying is meant to be completely unintelligible, or if it's just distorted enough to prevent me from understanding it. They speak entirely in katakana, as follows:

> バンわンコ…

> チミ二　ヨマッノタ？

> レソわ　イヘンタ。　リッユク　テシッテ。

I can't seem to find any of these words in dictionaries, and the fact they are using katakana makes me think that perhaps they are supposed to be speaking a foreign language that my character in game doesn't understand either, but I'm not sure. Is there any meaning here, or should I give up trying to translate it?

Comment: Makes perfect sense, but not as is, obviously.  All the kana are there but in random orders.  You should be able to decipher the first line at least.  Understanding the rest would require solid intermediate proficiency in "normal" Japanese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This character seems to be saying this in distorted Japanese:

> こんばんは…
> 道に迷ったの？
> それは大変。ゆっくりしてって。

Something like this is sometimes called ["typoglycemia"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposed_letter_effect#Internet_meme). Here's the Japanese version: [Is there a I awlyas tghuhot slpeling was ipmorantt! example in Japanese?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39692/5010)

Comment: +1 for "[typoglycemia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposed_letter_effect#Internet_meme)".