# What's meaning of デコグッズ、タモ

Tags: translation, meaning

[image]Dictionary silent, but in the manga page, I met two such words. What does it mean?デコグッズ and タモ. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The first could be a short for decoration goods... Can you provide the page and maybe some context?

Comment: Oh, sorry! Not problem! Wait a second

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, pretty sure デコグッズ is a short for デコレーショングッズ, which literally means "decoration goods". たも is a kind of a fishing net, you can see what it looks like if you search for it in Google Images. I don't know what dictionary you're using, but for example jisho.org knows what it is. Or were you confused by the fact that it's written in katakana here? That's actually pretty normal, see [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/why-are-katakana-preferred-over-hiragana-or-kanji-sometimes) for more info.