# What does ツノ in katakana mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

So, I was reading a commentary about an illustrator and it said :

> ツノと緑が大好きです

Does this ツノ really mean horn?

It's strange, so I'm kinda curious.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's simply 角【つの】 ("horn"). Some people actually like it (I'm not sure, but maybe as a variation of [ケモ耳](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moe_anthropomorphism#Animals) fandom)

Many native Japanese words are written in katakana [for various reasons](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1930/5010). In this specific case, the kanji 角 can be read as つの ("horn"), かど ("corner") or かく ("angle"), depending on the context. Writing it as ツノ is a fairly common approach to avoid confusion.