# Why is アタマ written in katakana in the following passage?

Tags: words, katakana, spelling

I am watching a [series](https://tezukaosamu.net/jp/about/story.html) of videos about the life of 手塚【てづか】治虫【おさむ】. In the video number 8, the word アタマ in 「子供のアタマ」 is spelled in katakana:

[image]

Is this a way to emphazise or highlight something? or what am I missing?

Also note that in the same slide, just some sentences before, あたま in 「頭のかたい」 is spelled in kanji, which makes it all the more intriguing. Why is the writer spelling あたま in katakana only for one occurrence of the word, an not for the others?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same reason why マンガ is commonly written in katakana. For some words, katakana makes them look "soft", "casual", "catchy", "friendly"...or whatever. This is why アタマ is often used in product names and catchphrases, as shown below:

[image]

As you can see, this has nothing to do with respect or humbleness. You can safely use アタマ referring to the brains of your (potential) customers.

Which word is commonly katakanized is fairly arbitrary, but アタマ, カラダ and ココロ are all common. Similar examples include ヘタ (下手), クソ (糞), カンタン (簡単), ベンリ (便利), オモテとウラ (表と裏), ミライ (未来), ワナ (罠) and タダ (只).

There are many other reasons to use katakana.

- To add an international flavor: [ニンジャ, ニッポン, ヒキコモリ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17799/5010)
- To add a "high-tech" flavor: [トヨタ, ホンダ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/31078/5010)
- To imply a derivative meaning is used: [オタク, ノド](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46870/5010)
- Simply the kanji is difficult and/or non-intuitive: [メチャクチャ, ツジツマ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15102/5010)
- Plain emphasis (akin to all-caps): ゼッタイ

Comment: 邪魔くさかったら申し訳ないのですが、話が噛み合っていない気がするので、先程の私の回答のコメントに付け加えさせていただきますと、手塚治虫が漫画を描き始めてた時の時代(1950~1960)の事を質問者のカットで書いているのではないかと思います。1990年以降の利用例ではないのではと感じています。

Comment: @kimiTanaka [この動画シリーズ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cv0vkZQ-esI&list=PL21RTOWbDjoiMSlc6evBCDT_Wwdaenuke&index=10)は21世紀に新たに作成されたものです。少々レトロな雰囲気は出していますけど、手塚が青年だった時代の細かい表記を注意深く反映して作ったものとは到底思えないので、その点は留意すべきかと。仮にこの部分が昔の表記を一字一句反映したものだったとしても、「当時は自分の息子の頭を指して "頭" と漢字で書くのは尊大に感じられるため憚られていた」…みたいな話を私は全く聞いたことがないのですが、kimi Tanaka さんはそういう話をご存知なのですか？

Comment: あくまで推測なので、narutoさんが仰るように「当時は自分の息子の頭を指して "頭" と漢字で書くのは尊大に感じられるため憚られていた」という時代であったかどうかは分かりませんが、対象とされるであろう読者層の1960年代くらいの子供ですと、団塊の世代辺りでしょうし、たくさん子供もいたでしょうし、高度経済成長期に当たるので、労働するのが精一杯で、そんなに個々の子供が今ほど大事に扱われていたとは思えないですし、「ただでさえ使えないアタマがさらに悪くなるぐらいのニュアンス」かなと想像しました。

Comment: 手塚プロダクションに確認しないと、どれだけ事実に基づいて書いたかどうかは分からないのですが、昔読んだ藤子不二雄の自伝的漫画 : [まんが道](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%93%E3%81%8C%E9%81%93)も創作が混ざっているようなので、narutoさんの仰るよう21世紀の読者の為の表現なのかも知れません。

Comment: @kimiTanaka 1000年前の古語では "君" という漢字が偉い人物を指す漢字だった、というのは有名ですが、流石に60年前の日本語は今と殆ど変わらないと思います。"頭" が偉い人専用の漢字だったとも思いませんし、片仮名で書かれた "アタマ" に "愚息" と同レベルの謙遜のニュアンスがあったというのも信じがたいです。片仮名で書くと軽くて「マンガっぽい」雰囲気が出るのは確かですが、それが謙遜と直接結びつく訳ではありません。例えば赤塚不二夫のマンガのキャラが「先生はアタマがようござんすね」みたいに喋ったとして、それが「先生の愚息」と同様の不適切表現になるとは想像しがたいです。

Comment: 頭がアタマと比べると、「銀行の頭取」のように荘重な感じがするのではないのかと、回答したつもりです。 narutoさんが挙げている『 [『数学者のアタマの中』](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E8%80%85%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD-D-%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A8%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB/dp/4000055321)』のMazda-RX8さんの書評には、こう書かれています、「読書家に強い影響力を持つと言われている全国紙A新聞にトンデモナイ書評が掲載されたために、 内容が良くないのでは？と誤解されているかもしれない本です。 また、**書名も内容とは少し異なる印象を与えるような微妙なものなので、これも誤解を受ける要因になっています。** 最近、偶然に読む機会があり、自分自身が「たいした本ではない」と誤解していたことが分かりました。 深い内容のトピックスが数式をあまり使わずに述べられており、数学的にセンスの良い「おしゃれな」話題が豊富です。」 太字強調部分のように、学者の頭脳・私的活動を「数学者のアタマの中」のような書き方をすると、学術書、数学啓蒙書の読者には、私の勝手な印象ですが、生半可な感じを与えるのではないかと思います。

Comment: 上手く説明できているかどうかは、分かりませんが、「先生の愚息」や子供を「愚息」と呼ぶのが不適切かどうかに関しては、日本人の感覚からすると、特に子供の名前を「悪魔」と名付けるわけではないですし、その家族の感性に委ねられる場合が多いのではないかと感じます。「先生はアタマがようござんすね」と褒めているであろうニュアンスが窺えるセリフのは異なり、今回のカットにおいて、私の印象では、「子供のアタマが悪くなる」のような書き方は子供の頭脳をそこまで大したものとして扱っていないのではないかという風に感じています。

Answer (score 1):

Purely speculative though, I think it's somewhat condescending description of children's head because the kanji :「頭」is normally used to describe an important person.

- [頭{かしら}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%A0%AD_%28%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%82%89%29/#jn-40824) is the head of the group of carpenters.
- [頭{とう}取{どり}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A0%AD%E5%8F%96) is the CEO of bank.
- [船頭{せんどう}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%88%B9%E9%A0%AD_%28%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%29/#jn-127066) is the captain of the ship.

So, the author wants to used「アタマ」for children's brain/mind/head in somewhat self-humiliating way. I think it is similar nuance that parents calling one's kid [愚息{ぐそく}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%84%9A%E6%81%AF/#jn-61700) or [豚児{とんじ}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%B1%9A%E5%85%90/) in Japanese culture.

Comment: 身内の人間の頭部や頭脳を指すときに「頭」という字を使うと失礼になるとか「アタマ」を使うと丁寧になるとかいう話は聞いたことがありません。「アタマ」「カラダ」「ココロ」の類はキャッチフレーズや商品名等でも「お客様」の頭や体や心を指してよく使われていますし、この表現自体に特にへりくだるようなニュアンスは感じないのですが。

Comment: @naruto アタマを片仮名で書くことに対して書いたつもりでした。漢字で「頭」と書くと子供に使うにしては幾分厳かな感じがするので、「アタマ」と著者は書き、マンガと同様に、そんなに現時点では重要ではないという事を言いたかったのかなと。

Comment: ええ、「頭」だと単純に堅苦しいので「マンガ」「ツジツマ」「オシャレ」などと同様に「アタマ」でカジュアル感・ポップ感を出しているという話なら理解できます。でも kimi Tanaka さんの回答は「アタマ」が相手への敬意と何か重要な関係があるかのようになっており、私はこれは敬意とは何も関係ないと思うのですが…。

Comment: @narutoさん　私は「マンガ」が社会的に市民権を得ていない時代の話ではないかと思い、カタカナで「マンガ」と書かれているのは一般の大人からすると得体の知れない対象ではなかったのかなと、手塚治虫が書いていた時代では。ドラえもんなどの作者の藤子不二雄がトキワ荘で、石ノ森章太郎などと作家として活躍できるよう奮闘していた時代はありませんでしたっけ？その時の用法としてはそういう意味だったのではないかと考えました。