# What is the purpose of using katakana in these instances?

Tags: katakana

I'm well aware of how katakana is typically used (borrowed words, onomatopoeia, etc).
I'm also aware of it being used in circumstances like demonstrating a distortion in the voice, or if the kanji of a word is complicated to read and/or write.

What I don't quite understand is the choice to use katakana as opposed to kanji with simple character words.
I understand that it's meant to give some kind of effect, but I don't know what. Bearing in mind that these words are spoken as normal, and no alternate readings are provided for "poetic" purposes.

As an example, why aren't these words written as 「人」, 「力」, 「君」, and 「振りをして」 respectively? Given that their kanji is far from complicated, that is.

(1)

> 《**ヒト**》と《神》　二つに分かれる命の軌跡
>   《神》を穢した《**ヒト**》の罪

(2)

> 変わり続けるその姿。引き寄せられるその**チカラ**。

(3)

> 舞い風の悪戯（いたずら）　**キミ**を連れて吹く
>   忘れない　あの日**キミ**もまた

(4)

> 泣きじゃくる**フリ**をしてみた

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are katakana preferred over hiragana or kanji sometimes?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/why-are-katakana-preferred-over-hiragana-or-kanji-sometimes) Probably these ヒト and チカラ are for mild emphasis; depending on the context, a reader may think there is some hidden meaning.

Comment: I can understand a need for emphasis with チカラ, which may explain that one. The use of ヒト in this instance, not so much. The example of ヒト is actually part of a song lyric. It could be possible that it is intended as a replacement for a word lacking. It tells the story of Gods and Humans living together in an Eden in the sky. Humans had wings, but there became a division, humans descended to the Earth and their wings were lost. Similarly, キミ may be favoured in the other example (a different song/story), as the speaker never actually learnt the other "person's" name.

Comment: Thank you for the information about キミ. By the way I edited my answer about ヒト.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)、(2)、(3)については、作者が、「人」「力」「君」という漢字の持っている広い意味ではなく、特定の意味に限定して用いたい為ではないかと思います。<del>(1)、</del> (2)については、与えられた例からだけでは限定された意味は分かりかねますが、もう少し前後の文脈が分かれば作者が限定したい意味は理解できるのではないかと思います。

> #### EDIT
>
> (1)については「ヒト」を「人」と「神」という対立概念として限定して用いていることを主張しているのではないでしょうか。一般に「人」と言う漢字を見て「人間」という言葉を類推する人は多いと思います。しかし、[ここ](http://gogen-allguide.com/ni/ningen.html)に書かれているように本来「人間」には「世間」という意味しかなく、「人」という意味はなかったようです。作者はこの辺りの知識を持っているので、「人間」ではない神と対峙｛たいじ｝する「人」ですよと言いたく「ヒト」と敢えてカタカナを用いたのではないでしょうか。

(3)についてはこの例だけでカタカナを用いた意図が分かります。一般に、「君」という漢字には多くの意味があり、しかも男性を指すニュアンスが強いように私は思います。ところが、「キミを連れて」の「キミ」は男性から見た女性を指しているように感じます。「君」という漢字が持っている男性色を払拭するために敢えてカタカナの「キミ」を使ったのだと思います。

(4)については(1)、(2)、(3)と違い、「消極的に強調する」ために用いていると思います。
私は、この用途で良くカタカナを用います。「消極的な強調」とは私の造語です。それは、何らかの理由で漢字で書くのを避けたいときに、仮にひらがなで書いてみると、そのひらがなが前後のひらがなで埋もれてしまい、見づらくなることがあります（**前後がひらがなですと必ず見づらくなります**。私のこうして書いている文の中で敢えて「ひらがな」と書いていますが、ところによっては「平仮名」と書いた方が読み易いような箇所もあります。「ひらがな」という文字が「ひらがな文字列」の中で埋もれてしまうからです）。単語と単語の間にスペースがある英語と違ってこれは日本語の表記上の欠点です。

**意図せずに見づらくなったひらがな表記**をどうしようかと悩んだ挙句{あげく}の果｛は｝てに、漢字に戻すのではなく、カタカナで書いてみます。ひらがな列の中のカタカナですので、目立ちます。しかし、強調したくてカタカナにしたのではありません。要するに「消極的に強調する」ために用いたと言うしかありません。単に視認性を上げただけですが、それでも強調したと取られる不安は残っております。

カタカナは外来語とか擬音語とか動植物とかを書き表すときに用いられるような特別のニュアンスがありますので、そのニュアンスを避ける方法としてあとはどのような方法があるのでしょうか。**今使う人は少ない**ですが、[圏点](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%8F%E7%82%B9)という方法があります。これも何だかその文字列を強調しているようで嫌ですが、ひらがなで押し通そうとすると圏点を用いるのも別の解決策かも知れません。

> 因みに、**圏点{けんてん}** は、傍点{ぼうてん}とか脇点{わきてん}とも言われ、日本語を書き表す場合、文字の強調を行うときに、親文字{おやもじ}の脇または上下に付加する点のことです。

漢字でスパッと書いてしまえば楽ですが、読む人のことを考えるとそれもできないことが多々あります。そんなとき、一旦書いた文字列を見ながら、私は、普段次のような試行錯誤をしています。ワープロだからできる試行錯誤です。

- 泣きじゃくる振りをしてみた → 泣きじゃくるふりをしてみた → 泣きじゃくるフリをしてみた → 泣きじゃくる振（ふ）りをしてみた → 泣きじゃくるフリをしてみた → 泣きじゃくる振りをしてみた　（私の思い：多分「振り」ってちゃんと読んでくれるだろうな。）
- 秋も深まると公園のいろどりも一段と → 秋も深まると公園のイロドリも一段と → 秋も深まると公園の彩も一段と → 秋も深まると公園の彩（いろどり）も一段と　（私の思い：「彩」ではちゃんと読めないし、「いろどり」では色がイメージとして伝わらない。「イロドリ」では見た目がオドロオドロしい。ひらがなを付けて漢字で行こう。）

Comment: Thank you, you have given me something to think about. There are so many factors to consider! To note though, 「キミ」 in this song/novel is from a woman's perspective, referring to a travel companion she never seemed to learn the name of. The character in question was male, and of a beast humanoid race. Perhaps this is a reason why 「キミ」 was favoured.

Comment: あの・・「見ずらく」は「見づらく」ですよね・・？さっき(８分前)編集したんですけど、元に戻されちゃった(４分前)んで・・

Comment: @Chocolate: それだけが気になって探していたのですが、手許の辞書が悪くて見つからず、無責任で書いてしまいました。反省です。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @Chocolate: 「ヒト」の件でEDITしておりましたので、せっかくの編集を台無しにしたようです。申し訳ありません。ご指摘どおり修正しました。