# Kanji or hiragana? 駄目です vs だめです

Tags: kanji, hiragana

Which is the correct or more common way of writing

駄目です

or

だめです?

My text book says it means "it's is not possible".

Comment: だめ has a variety of meanings from merely “no!” and “don’t!” to “that’s not allowed” or “that’s not the right way to do it”. i’m no expert on how to write it though it seems to me that more frequently you would see だめ or even ダメ (for more emphasis). the kanji, for me, seem to weaken the force of it—and my guess is that using kanji for だめ would give a literary feel.

Comment: See also [Why are katakana preferred over hiragana or kanji sometimes?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1932/78).

Answer (score 0):

Either is OK. Japanese use kanji to express classy atmosphere and use hiragana to express simplicity.