# Is it の or not in this case?

Tags: grammar

Is the 2nd image (one below the google translate) more accurate?
Is the のですが just completely wrong or?

Also I know the Google translate is wrong at the end because I accidentally had a new line after "call".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both machine translations are not very natural. I would translate this as:

> I want to call him but I'm sleep so I won't call him tonight.
>
> - 彼に電話したい**の**ですが、眠いので今夜はしません。
> - 彼に電話をしたい**の**ですが、眠いので今晩はやめておきます。

Either way, の before ですが is perfectly natural. This type of の is called [explanatory-の](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/explanatory-noda/), and it's perfectly natural to use it to set up a context, as in your sentence. See the "preliminary remarks" section in the linked article. See also: [What is the meaning of ～んです/～のだ/etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010)

Besides, you need a contrastive-は after 今夜/今晩. This is something easily forgotten by English speakers, but it's important.

Comment: does it still sound natural without the の?

Comment: @user71207 It's still valid without の, but の is strongly desirable at least in this context. I don't know the exact rules regarding when の is optional in "preliminary remarks".

Comment: Also I am curious, why do you use だめ in katakana in your user profile?

Comment: @user71207 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15102/5010